# PHP Gives Me Wrong Result Of Subtraction With Floating Number

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
<?php

$a = 991.3;

$float = floor($a);
$float = $a - $float;

echo $float;
```

it gives me this as result:

```
0.29999999999995
```

why not `0.3`? and how to get `0.3` instead of `0.29999999999995`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because PHP's precision with floating point numbers is not exact. This is warned of in the [php manual entry about floating point number](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

If you want mathematical precision for different operations, you must use PHP's `bcmath` extension. I bet it must be compiled already in your PHP installation, but if not, you can always google how to install it. :)

[These are the functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [PHP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/ref.bc.php) for doing operations with precisions number.

```
<?php

$a = '1.234';
$b = '5';

echo bcsub($a, $b);     // -3
echo bcsub($a, $b, 4);  // -3.7660

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget about install it using apt-get: sudo apt-get install php-bcmath